# How can I edit textures from linked particle systems?

Tags: particles, linked-data

I have set up a scene and want to use it as a library. The scene includes several hair particle systems to distribute and animate vegetation. These particle systems are, in turn, controlled by image textures for the hair density.

Here is the Particle System from the original library .blend showing

A) The Texture tab in the Properties Toolbox

B) The texture editing icon next to the selected texture.

[image]

After linking the various objects into my new .blend file, I realised that I need to edit the hair density textures. But there was no way to do that in the linked systems as everything was ghosted.

[image]

So I localised the particle systems, and then the textures.

[image]

Now I can select different textures, and even add new default ones, but I cannot edit them because both buttons A and B are still missing.

Is there something else I need to localise to get the Texture buttons back, or is this just a bug?